# File permissions in cygwin and MVFS

Tags: permissions, cygwin, clearcase, chmod

I am using Cygwin with a dll version of 1.5.19 (yes, out-of-date, I know, but we're doing it for configuration control reasons).  All my files (existing and newly created) show up with permissions 644, despite a umask of 022.  Also, using chmod doesn't change the permissions.  I have ntsec set in the CYGWIN environment variable.  I need to be able to add execute permissions; is there anything I can try to fix this or is it a lost cause?

---

A much later note: I realized that a key part of the problem is that the files I was trying to chmod were in a ClearCase dynamic view, which uses MVFS.  I still have not found way to successfully set the execute permissions, though.

Answer (score 6):

Edit `/etc/passwd` to change the default value for GID for your user to 545 (i.e. NT 'Users' group)  instead of 513 ('None' group).

Review system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `$HOME/.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for default umask settings.

Even if default, do try to set CYGWIN variable in NT system environment to "binmode ntsec".

Let me know if problems disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You need `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files for permissions to work correctly.

See [Why doesn't `chmod` work?](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.chmod) in the [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html)

and

[File Permissions](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-files) in the [Cgywin User's Guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html)

Comment: I have both of these files, set up with the SIDs as described in those links.  Still no luck.

Comment: Hmmm... works for me.  I'm using 1.5.25 and have `ntea` set in CYGWIN (although the latest documentation says that both `ntea` and `ntsec` have been removed.)

Comment: Is the drive mounted with anything unusual?  Like `noacl`?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  All the mount points were created automatically, and they don't list 'noacl' when I list them with 'mount'.

Comment: Ok, dumb question: Is the drive NTFS?  Last thing to suggest:  use "mount --system --binary "C:" /c" and try it. I've got all my local drives and common network shares mounted explicitly.  Shouldn't make a difference, but...